# Getting user's Play Store country

Tags: android

There are many ways how to get user's country trough location services. However country obtained this way does not always correspond with the country associated with the user's Play Store.

Is there a way to get user's Play Store country directly via code?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way you can get the play store country in the Android SDK.

But you can use the **getSkuDetails()** method in Android In-app Billing API. It will return you a JSON.

In the JSON look for the field **price_currency_code**  to get the currency code of the currency being used in the play store account. From the currency, you can get the country.

See here for details - https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails

Comment: Thanks. But it not work because several countries can have one currency

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is now out of date. A way to fetch `BillingConfig` has been [added to the API.](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingConfigResponseListener)

Call `getBillingConfigAsync` on your `BillingClient`. Then in the listener callback upon success, `BillingConfig` will be returned. This config contains the country code in ISO-3166-1 alpha2 format